# Graph API HTTPS 400 When trying to assign managers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to assign managers to members in my organization via Graph API to Azure AD. I seem to have done everything according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but I still get a Bad Request, can you spot what i'm doing wrong?

```
url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/manager/$ref'
params = {"@odata.id":f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{manager_id}"}

response = requests.put(url, headers= headers, params= params)

if response.status_code == 204:
    print(f'user {user_email} successfully transfered to leader {synergy_manager_email} from leader {ad_manager_email}')
else:
    print(f'fail. user {user_email} transfer to leader {synergy_manager_email} from leader {ad_manager_email} returned status code:{response.status_code}')
```

Thank you

I tried exactly what is described in the documentation and expected status code 204 in the response

Comment: A 204 status code is used when the server successfully processes the request, but there is no content to return to the client. This is typically used for requests where the client wants to indicate that it has finished processing a request, such as a DELETE request. . . But in the case of this question a PUT request.

Comment: Hi! A code 204 is exactly whats I expect, but for some reason it only returns code 400:


fail. user transfer returned status code:400

Comment: A status code of 400 indicates a "Bad Request" in the context of HTTP responses. This means that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).